# installing a new motherboard in a hp xw6200 pc case

Tags: motherboard

I have recently purchased a new motherboard. However when I go to install it into my HP workstation xw-6200 case, the standoffs for the original motherboard are set where the screw holes for the two processors reside. What should I do??

Answer (score 0):

do this

1. confirm the FORM FACTOR of the Case
2. Confirm the FORM FACTOR of the Motherboard

they should both be the Same Form Factor,
in todays day, they should be ATX

if they are not the same, that's your problem, the form factor's have to match

if they ARE both ATX, then Your Putting the board in Incorrectly, Try another Way,

being a Square Board you only have 4 Possible choices and only 1 is correct

if you could post a picture of what your doing that would help a lot

Comment: i think your using a Proprietry From Factor HP Case, because if you examine the Case Specs,  Here   (http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay&spf_p.prp_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c00215315-3%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) and you compare that with ATX Specs or it's variants here  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX) You won't find form factor that is 17.3 x 17.3   you need a new case ATX form factor